# Laterals from Surface to Bottom Hole

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, oil-gas

Is there a way using ArcGIS 10.3, when you have points for Surface Well and Bottom Hole... with API numbers, match up the API numbers and have a "LATERAL LINE" be drawn without hand drawing in each one?

Answer (score 2):

Look in ArcToolbox under:

Data Management Tools -> Features -> Points to Line

Specify your input and output feature class, and under `Line Field` you would select the well API.

A word of caution though, you will need to check your results if you have multiple bottom holes for a well.

Comment: what is that supposed to do?  It does not address the question of generating Lateral lines? I tried that and all I came up with is a polyline shp file of 16 lines of 3,061 wells. Blank shp file.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant to connect the bottom hole to the surface location. If that's not it, I'm unfamiliar with lateral lines in this context.

Comment: I thank you for taking your time out to help.  I'm sure there is a way but probably takes a lot of program scripting.